# Android Studio - Espresso jar downloaded but imports not detected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-espresso

I have included expresso gradle dependency into my project.

build.gradle:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
```

It has downloaded the jar, which is visible under external libraries:

[image: expresso-import]

But imports are not detected while using them in class. For example: when I write `onView(withId(R.id.textView)).perform( ...`, android studio reports - `cannot resolve symbol - onView`.

I tried invalidate caches and rebuilding. Am I missing something here ?

```
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class RegisterActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<RegisterActivity> mRegisterActivity = new ActivityTestRule
            <>(RegisterActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void test_text_views() {
        onView. // onView is not imported directly. Even force use of android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView does not work
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are in the wrong src folder? The androidTestCompile dependencies are only available under `src/androidTest/java`

Comment: Using correct folder `src/androidTest/java`

Comment: Do you get same error when running instrumentation tests from command line?

Comment: Instrument Tests work fine. Only when I started writing test for Activities, I had to use expresso, which is when I started facing this issue.

Comment: Using Espresso is instrumentation testing (at least for me). Would be great if you can post sample test class code including the imports do you use.

Comment: Added more detail to question, please check.
I have not yet used expresso in any of my tests yet.

Comment: Is `onView.` an copy paste mistake or do you try to use the method as variable? Which part of `android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView( )` can't be resolved?